# How to Calculate Quality Score in Google Adsense

Tags: adsense

I have a task to build Google Adsense-Like Ads Engine. I am curious how Quality Score in Google Adsense is calculated. Anyone share please :) Tq

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [Google Support Page](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2454010?hl=en)? They explain what influences the Quality Score. If you're looking for the detailed algorithm, I don't think Goolge will tell. ;)